# Install ROS Kinetic on MacOS under a separate Anaconda environment

Tags: python, macos, macos-sierra, ros

I'm installing ROS Kinetic on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 under a seperate environment under Python Anaconda distribution.

Here is my python version(my seperate python environment in Anaconda is called "ros-kinetic"):

```
(ros-kinetic)  jizhe@jizhedeMacBook-Pro  ~/ros_catkin_ws  python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I followed the guide: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source.

When I execute the "rosdep install" command, I got the following error:

```
(ros-kinetic)  jizhe@jizhedeMacBook-Pro ~/ros_catkin_ws  rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
actionlib: No definition of [python-wxtools] for OS [osx]
catkin: No definition of [google-mock] for OS [osx]
roslisp: No definition of [google-mock] for OS [osx]
```

Obviously, there is something wrong with the package "python-wxtools" and "google-mock".

I've already install the wxpython via "brew install wxpython", and here is the wxpython info:

```
(ros-kinetic)  jizhe@jizhedeMacBook-Pro  ~/ros_catkin_ws  brew info wxpython
wxpython: stable 3.0.2.0 (bottled)
Python bindings for wxWidgets
https://www.wxwidgets.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/wxpython/3.0.2.0_1 (1,108 files, 37.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-02-24 at 03:56:21
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/wxpython.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: wxmac ✔
==> Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
mkdir -p /Users/jizhe/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/jizhe/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

And I've already run the command:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
$ echo "$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

So, what's wrong with the package "google-mock" and "python-wxtools", how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try installing with --skip-keys python-wxtools --skip-keys google-mock. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is [a ticket](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/110#issuecomment-363909128) for this issue. Basically the workaround is to install [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) manually. Not sure what's wrong with `python-wxtools`.

edit: If you're using [ros-install-osx](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx), you can add the following lines to your `rosdeps.yaml` file:

```
google-mock:
  osx:
    homebrew:
      packages: []
```

Comment: rjstar1996's answer works for me, thank your all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question from a Google search, just for your information in 2021 installing ROS in conda also on macOS should be much straightforward, see the following links:

- https://medium.com/robostack/cross-platform-conda-packages-for-ros-fa1974fd1de3
- https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic